# Extend and persist cart line item with a struct object

Tags: shopware, shopware6

What would be the correct way to extend a LineItem with an Object (Struct). Since a few versions only scalar values are allowed in the payload, I'm currently bypassing the validation by using the "replacePayload" method.

I want the data to be persisted in the database and it should later also be taken over into the OrderLineItem, as it is currently already the case with the payload.

And I want the data to be available as an array/object in the APIs

My current workaround:

```php
class LineItemSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            BeforeLineItemAddedEvent::class => 'extendLineItem'
        ];
    }

    public function extendLineItem(BeforeLineItemAddedEvent $event)
    {
        $payload = $event->getLineItem()->getPayload();

        $payload['custom_key'] = new CustomStruct(...);

        $event->getLineItem()->replacePayload($payload);
    }

}
```